# making sure all my tabular content is vertically aligned?

Tags: html, css

Im having trouble making my table contents vertically aligned and was wondering if you could help, ive added border-collapse:collapse to  and given my  border in order for the table styling to work correctly in IE7, if anyone has any suggestions on how I can produce a consistent table layout that would be great. btw I'm using a table as this content is worthy of a table.

CSS

```
#myTable{width:810px;margin:0 auto;border-top:1px solid #f00;height:200px;overflow:auto;border-collapse:collapse;}
#myTable tr{padding-right:0;margin-right:0;display:block;}
#myTable td{float:left;border-bottom:1px solid #f00;padding-right:0;margin:0;font-size:16px;height:50px;padding:10px 0}
#myTable .title{width:199px;}
#myTable .description{width:481px;color:#ffc500;}
#myTable .description a{color:#ffc500;}
#myTable .logo{width:127px;text-align:right;}
#myTable .logo a{display:block;line-height:0;vertical-align:middle}
#myTable .logo img{vertical-align:middle;}
```

HTML

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td class="title">Title</td>
        <td class="description"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum sit amet dolar</a></td>
            <td class="logo"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/130x50/000/fff" width="130" height="50" /></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="title">Title</td>
        <td class="description"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum sit amet dolar</a></td>
            <td class="logo"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/130x50/000/fff" width="130" height="50" /></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="title"></td>
        <td class="description"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum sit amet dolar</a></td>
            <td class="logo"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/130x50/000/fff" width="130" height="50" /></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="title">Title</td>
        <td class="description"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum sit amet dolar</a></td>
            <td class="logo"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/130x50/000/fff" width="130" height="50" /></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is a link to my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EEwvG/1/
​

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float` from your `TD`. Write like this

```
#myTable td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you set `vertical-align: top` for `td` you will see the same alignment also on IE7 (I assume you want top alignment, since on IE7 cells are middle aligned)

As aside note, you could avoid to assign `float: left` for your cells, it has no effect)